# read from .txt file and convert in to List<Map>

Tags: java, xml

i have heavy .txt file. it contains a format Like this:

```
  0      1    2    3    4    5    6    7   ... n
0 A,     B,   c,   D,   E,   F,   G,   H,  
1 AA,    BB,  CC,  DD,  EE,  FF,  GG,  HH, 
2
3
.
.
n
```

i want to save each row in Map. 
for example in first row:  map<0,A> .  map<1,B>, Map<2,C>,...
then i want to save this maps in List. for example i want to save 100 rows in List.
for example if i write this function: "" list.get(1).get(4); ""  i recived "EE"
it means first i have to go in 1 row, then i go to 4 and recive "EE".
could you please guidance me how to solve this problem?
i read some article about "spring batch" .and it related what i want
could you please help me how can i fix this problem?

```
public class spliter {
    static int w=0;
    private static HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    private static List<Map<Integer, String>> list=new ArrayList<Map<Integer,String>>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String string = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\test.txt"));

            while( (string = reader.readLine()) != null ) {

                String[] parts = string.split(",");
                int i=parts.length;
                for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
                    map.put(j, parts[j]);
                }           
                list.add(map);
                w++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should worry about Spring Batch yet. This is a programming problem - adding Spring Batch into the mix will only complicate things. What have you written so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something this simple can be solved using a Scanner to read each line and then `String.split(...)` to split each line. Something like:

```
while line exists
  read line into String using Scanner
  split String using String#split(...)
  use array from split to create a list
  add above list to master list
end while
```

Note that you can contain this in a list of lists, without the need of a Map, at all. `List<List<String>>` should do it for you.

I think that it would be more instructive to you for us to give you general advice like this, and then to see what you can do with it.

I have made into a Community Wiki, so all might contribute easily to this answer and so no-one will get reputation for up-votes.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same, i did it with yours in mind

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
public class Spliter {
    private static List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<> ();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\829784\\Desktop\\Repo\\Documentacion Repositorio\\test.txt"));
        String line = "";
        String firstline = reader.readLine();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Map < String, Object > map = new TreeMap < > ();
            String[] partsfirstline = firstline.split(";");
            String[] parts = line.split(";");
            int i = parts.length;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                map.put(partsfirstline[j], parts[j]);
            }
            list.add(map);
        }
        System.out.println(list.get(0).values());
        System.out.println(list.get(1).values());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could us something like this

```
public class ArrayReader {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<String >> array = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));){
    String line;
    while ((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        array.add(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}